How much higher pressure is required for small diameter wheels?
Since buying a folder with 20" wheels, I've noticed that they need higher pressure than similar width 26" or 700C wheels, and the handling suffers more suddenly when the pressure gets too low (the latter may be just that everything is a little more twitchy with a short wheelbase and small wheels, whatever the pressure, but it does repeatably feel like it's fine one day and controlled by a squirrel the next).
But how much higher should the pressure be?  Tyre pressure calculators never seem to cover small wheels and anyway the front/rear weight distribution is likely to be different.  I can get the handling acceptable by feel (I usually top up with the pump built in to the seatpost, which doesn't have a gauge, so I'm likely to be working by feel anyway) but I'd like numbers to check against and to consider efficiency.

"how much higher should the pressure be?" Do you mean how much higher should you inflate beyond the recommended pressure stamped on the tire or are you wondering why the recommended pressure is higher than a similar tire for a larger wheel?

Never done this myself - the 28mm front wheel on my 20"/406mm folder gets 80-85 psi same as the road bike, and the 2" rear gets 55-60 PSI

@DavidD neither of those.  The recommended pressure (as on most decent tyres) is a range - quite a wide range in the case of Marathon Green - and yes, both max and min are higher for 20" than 26".  The higher maximum is presumably because of the total stress on the small tyre. But I'd never run at the maximum pressure on full-size wheels; I'm heavy but not that heavy (and Marathons can be used on cargo bikes and tandems so they're rated to pretty high loads and pressures).  So it's more a case of "how much higher within the printed range should I go for?"

@Criggie that seems high for me for 28mm road wheels (Silca says 74psi front for my total of 100kg on 28mm, poor road surface). I might pump a commuter up to that so I can pump less often, but it would be harsh for long rides.  So maybe that's why you don't need to run the folder harder than the road bike

I keep my velomobile 20" tires on about the maximum which is molded on the side wall of the tire and so do most riders on the Dutch language recumbent forum. I think it is 5 to 6 bar depending on the tire, some go up to 7 bar.
On my recumbent folding bike I keep the pressure lower. Such that I can just start to deform the tire and I top up when I can really press it in. This is more comfortable and still handles well.
This seems common for more open bikes.
Say 4 bar, maybe 3 to 5, 1 to 2 bar under max.

Mine go up to 7 bar even at 40+mm, but that's because they're Marathons which are heavy duty. Running that hard seems like too much but maybe I'll try it (on the back, a little softer on the front)
